# My script does not exist?

Tags: unity-game-engine

fellow Unitians. I am having problems with my script now. It is saying it doesn't exist at all, when it is right there in the folder on Unity. I don't know how to solve this problem, and I'm getting this error only when I try to add it to an object already in the game. Please help?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwordSwing : MonoBehaviour {

    private float swingDuration = 0.5f;
    private float swingSpeed = 0.22f;

    private float swingTimer = 0f;
    private bool swinging = false;
    private Vector3 startRot;

    void Start () {
        startRot = transform.eulerAngles;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !swinging) {
            swinging = true;
        }   

        if (swinging) {
            swingTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (swingTimer < (swingDuration / 2)) {
                transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startRot, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), swingSpeed);
            }

            if (swingTimer > (swingDuration / 2)) {
                transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles, startRot, swingSpeed);
            }

            if (swingTimer > swingDuration) {
                swingTimer = 0f;
                swinging = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error, and when are you seeing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monobehaviours must be in files named for their class name. Your class must be in a file called

`SwordSwing.cs`

or it won't work.

Comment: It's ok! These things happen. :)